# Error when loading .mat file with scipy.io (ValueError: Mat 4 mopt wrong format)

Tags: matlab, scipy, h5py

I'm currently trying to load a .mat file in python using scipy and the following bit of code:

```
from scipy import io as sio
data= "file.mat"
output= sio.loadmat(data)
```

However when running the command I get the error:

```
ValueError: Mat 4 mopt wrong format, byteswapping problem?
```

What does this error message mean? Is there an issue with the file I'm trying to load?
I'm quite the novice when it comes to programming so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated : ) If there is a better way to load .mat files in python I'm open to hearing those too.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your reply, I found out that these files are 7.3 MAT-files, HDF5 file types, so they aren't supported by SciPy, will probably try h5py instead

Comment: I'm going to add a couple of tags so this is easier to find.  As more 7.3 becomes more common we see more of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this error before, but it is produced by line 113 in scipy/scipy/io/matlab/mio4.py

```
def read_header(self):
    ''' Read and return header for variable '''
    data = read_dtype(self.mat_stream, self.dtypes['header'])
    name = self.mat_stream.read(int(data['namlen'])).strip(b'\x00')
    if data['mopt'] < 0 or data['mopt'] > 5000:
        raise ValueError('Mat 4 mopt wrong format, byteswapping problem?')
    ...
```

Normally `loadmat` is the right file loader, at least among the supported types:

> v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2 matfiles are supported.

Do you know anything about how this file was saved in MATLAB?  Any format specifications such as these?